# How to remove a particular content inside a div using Hpricot

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I have the following html structure

```
  <div id="rn_answertext">
    <p>asdasdasdas</p>
    <p>asdasdasdas</p>
    <p>asdasdasdas</p>
    <h3>asdasdasdas</h3>
    <div id="test">Content to be excluded</div>
  </div>
```

What I need is, when I search for div id="rn_answertext" I need to get all the contents except that in the div with id=test

My current code is

```
  result = doc.search("div#rn_answertext").inner_html
```

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the div you want, then find the div inside you'd like to remove:

```
div = (doc/"div#rn_answertext")
(div/"#test").remove
puts div.to_s
```

Answer (score 2):

> div = doc.search("//div[@id='rn_answertext']")
>
> div.search('//div[@id="test"]').remove.html

Will give you the rn_answertext div content except test div.